# How to convert dataframe to list without adding more decimal places in python

Tags: python, list, dataframe, rounding, tolist

I have a dataframe. The values are 5 decimal places as shown in the first image.

After I use `df.values.tolist()` to convert to list, some became more than 5 decimal places as shown the 2nd image.

How can I convert to list and keep the original decimal places? I don't want to use loop and round them after because I have over 30 million rows and it takes too much time. Thanks.

[image]
[image]

Comment: your dataframe has the same # of decimal places as the list, it is just set to display fewer places. why are you converting the df to a list? do you intend to display it somewhere? if so, where?

Comment: I need to do conditional statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [rounding](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.round.html) the df first and then converting to list

```
df[numeric_columns] = df[numeric_columns].round(5)
df = pd.concat([df[non_numeric_columns], df[numeric_columns]]), axis=1)
```

Then

`df.values.tolist()`